# Development and deployment of cross platform Linux servers

Tags: deployment, cross-platform

I'm trying to create a template installation of Linux to deploy on multiple single-board computer servers, with slightly different hardware and operating systems. My understanding is that this would be an ideal application for Docker, except for the fact that it doesn't handle Armbian/Raspbian (32-bit) systems. To clarify, when I say "template installation of Linux", I mean that I will be starting with a base OS install, and then want to install/configure a bunch of packages/applications, make some configuration changes etc. Ideally, I want to develop the system in a virtualised installation of Ubuntu, and then deploy it across a number of servers. I suppose I could just save the command history and turn it into a deployment script, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Product recommendation and capacity planning questions are off-topic here at Server Fault.

Comment: @Paul Thanks; any suggestions as to where would be more appropriate?

Comment: Discussion forums are better suited to this sort of question, but for SE you could try Software recommendations, but even they have their requirements.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it but ansible might be a good solution- its meant for large-scale deployment / host management. I DO know a lot of people that use it for this purpose though.

heres the install guide
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html

installing packages to a bunch of endpoints
https://opensource.com/article/20/9/install-packages-ansible

just make a few separate playbooks for installing on raspbian / ubuntu. Probably wont be too much of a difference if you dont though.